# Is it possible to only silence certain notifications?

Tags: notifications, htc-droid-incredible, calls, ringtone

I'm running Android 2.2 FroYo on an HTC Droid Incredible. When I go to bed, I want to turn off all notifications except for incoming phone calls, which I still want to receive. Is this possible, either natively or through an application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this question to a friend and he suggested the [AudioManager Widget](http://www.cyrket.com/p/android/com.smartandroidapps.audiowidget/). It allows you to control volumes for Alarm, Media, Alerts, Ringer, System, and Voice Calls independently. It also allows you to toggle vibrate for alerts and ringer independently. So far, it seems to be a solid app.

Answer (score 1):

The [Setting Profiles](http://www.probeez.com/) should be able to do something like that. You can set up a profile that turns off all notifications for when you get ready for bed. Then, add a rule that overrides the profile - turning notifications back on only for incoming calls:

- Create a new rule
- Add Incoming Call condition - this can be set to a specific contact group of just to <> depending on your preferences
- Add Activate Profile action to activate a different profile where sound is On and/or some custom ring tone specified

They currently have two versions of the app - a [Lite](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.probeez.liteprofiles) and [Full](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.probeez.profiles). The Lite version is limited to one rule at a time. You might be able to try it out with the Lite version and then get the Full if it works out for you.

QR Code for Setting Profiles Lite:

[image: QR Code for Setting Profiles Lite]

QR Code for Setting Profiles Full:

[image: QR Code for Setting Profiles Full]

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Tasker](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) or [Locale](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.twofortyfouram.locale). They can be configured to do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a profile and switch it by long pressing the power button. At least on Cyanogen, there is a menu item Change Profile. On stock Sense ROM it is likely there, too.