# What volume setting do the Twitter and Facebook apps obey?

Tags: notifications, facebook, volume-control, twitter

I asked a question about [silencing only certain sounds](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/337/is-it-possible-to-only-silence-certain-notifications/385#385) and decided to go with the AudioManager widget, which is working quite well. My main uses are to silence everything but alarms and the ringer when I'm sleeping and everything when I'm in class. However, if I get a notification from Facebook or Twitter (both the official apps by Facebook and Twitter, respectively) at night, they still go off, which makes me think that these apps either use the ringer volume (instead of the alert volume) or some volume that AudioManager doesn't have control over.

The volume controls provided by AudioManager are Alarm Volume, Music Volume, Alerts Volume, Ringer Volume, System Volume, and Voice call Volume. Alarm volume is always 7/7, music volume is where ever it was last time I listened to music (in the car, I have it 15/15, and usually 8/15 when I'm listening with earbuds), alerts is 7/7 during the day and 0/7 at night, ringer is always 7/7, system is 7/7 during the day and 0/7 at night, and voice call volume is 3/5.

So, my questions:

(1) What volume do these apps actually use for notifications?

(2) Is there an easy way (without having to open both apps and turn off notifications at night, then turn them back on) to silence these notifications? This includes possibly switching away from AudioManager to another free application.

Comment: When you develop an app you are able to choose which volume to use (or rather what kind of sound you are using). At least for alarms, ringtones and notifications.
I have the same problem as Tomas Owens, Twitter is waking me up even thou notifications are muted (using AudioManager).
Im guessing they are using ringer or alarm volume.
Best is to ask them i guess.

I might add that Im using Cyanogen 7 Nightly on my Nexus so my experiences could be due to the custom rom part.

Comment: @Alex: I'm getting the same thing on Cyanogen 6.1 now and the stock HTC Incredible ROM when I asked this question. I suppose I should contact Twitter and Facebook or file a bug report/feature request.

Comment: I've been seatching for a solution to this as well. I've always used Quick Profiles and I have daytime and nighttime profiles made. At night I have all sounds off except alarms and ringtones. Annoyingly the twitter and facebook apps still get their sounds through. VERY annoying... time to do more googling I think. Hope I find an answer, I hate having to go into the app to silence them every time it's such a hassle.

Answer (score 1):

1) App notifications use the Ringer volume for how loud the notification is played.

2) You could use an application like Locale or Tasker to automatically silence your Ringer volume during the night.  Then you could create exceptions if you need for certain people to be able to call you during the night.

Comment: The GMail and Google Voice apps don't obey 1 (they appear to follow the Alerts volume, and not the ringer, since I've gotten emails with the ringer on and Alerts off and no notification sound) so it's not all apps. And I don't just want certain people to be able to call me - if I'm getting a phone call, I would like to assume that it might be important, even if I don't know the number. If this is indeed the case, I suppose individually muting applications (or looking into creating an app that manages the notification settings of other apps) might be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

[Quick Settings](http://www.appbrain.com/app/quick-settings/com.bwx.bequick) has a separate "Notification Volume" which for me controls all of my apps notifications (although I have FB and Twitter notification off at the source).  Another app I use is [Quick Profiles](http://www.appbrain.com/app/quick-profiles/de.softxperience.android.quickprofiles) for fast switching between preset profiles.  This app also can control the "Notification Volume".  I have a specific profile set for when I sleep that turns off all notifications.  Another thing you could do is turn off AutoSync at night which is a toggle on the stock Power Widget.  That way you'd still get calls and texts but it would update any of your email or apps.

For the record, Quick Settings can control the following volume levels:

- Ringer Volume
- Notification Volume
- Media Volume
- Alarm Volume
- Voice Call Volume
- System Volume

as well as the Master Volume.

Comment: I was just testing. It seems like every app I have, except for Twitter and Facebook, obeys Alert/Notification volume settings. Twitter and Facebook appear to, like Bryan says, use the Ringer volume. I've never developed an Android application, but I would suspect this is a problem with the Twitter and Facebook apps.

Comment: That is strange that they'd do it that way.  That being said, I'd say you best bet would be to toggle the AutoSync before you go to bed.